# IntelliJ: terminal crashed and wouldn't start again

Tags: intellij-idea

I ran some **ssh** session via terminal in IntelliJ. Session eventually timed out and **I had to kill the process** with CTRL+C.

Whenever I start my terminal now, IntelliJ wouldn't start new session. I see only blinking cursor:
[image: no shell here]

I tried disabling and re-enabling plugin again, but it didn't help.

I am using OS X and my terminal settings point to standard bash (tried zsh and fish as well, no change).

Comment: Does IntelliJ's Event Log have any errors/warnings?

Comment: unfortunatelly not ...